# Is my hard drive done for?

Tags: hard-drive

The laptop, when booting into Windows XP, started to display BSOD with *Unmountable Boot Volume* message.

I tried to `chkdsk /r`:

> The volume appears to contain one or more unrecoverable problems

`fdisk` also doesn't work. It produces an error that I can't remember now.

`Linux LiveCD GParted smartcl` scan gave the *PASSED* log message. But trying to format the hard drive using `GParted` on first attempt showed *input/output error*, but clicking Retry would yield the *Everything-went-good* message. Yet, refreshing the `GParted`'s display would still show my hard drive as being NTFS file system with about 6GB used.

Then I tried to use Partition Wizard Boot CD:

Same as with `GParted` - Partition Wizard would display my hard drive as NTFS file system with about 6GB used. I could actually right click and "explore" the NTFS partition, and see my files. But I'm not trying to recover them because there's nothing on that hard drive I need anymore, I want to format it and install a different operating system.

Trying to use "Delete" the partition gives the same result, after **Applying** the pending delete process, the NTFS partition remains untouched (just like with GParted). Trying to format the partition takes a really long time (for every ~30 minutes, only 1% increase in the progress bar). Running Surface Scan made my laptop restart, every time.

Also, I downloaded a Disk Fitness Test program from the manufacturer of my hard drive and ran an *Advanced Test*, which said that my hard drive passed it. But running format utility prompts an error saying that the device is corrupted.

Fixing MBR also didn't change anything.

So, is my hard drive finished for good? I'm confused between successful tests, ability to actually explore the partition, and receiving all kinds of errors trying to format or delete the hard disk.

Comment: I've seen similar errors caused by usually one of 2 things, either the MBR on the drive has a error in which case use hex editor to rewrite it, or indeed your hard drive is done. If you do a lot of partitioning, as it seems you do, it may be the MBR. Have you tried using dd to wipe the disk?

Comment: @user88311
You could say I've been partitioning alot on this hard drive. But I've always partitioned the hdd entirely and it always had one big partition. I haven't used dd because I don't really know what it is or how to use it.

Comment: @user88311
Found about dd here: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_wipe_a_hard_drive_clean_in_Linux#Wiping_the_entire_disk

Ran the first command example to wipe the disk and put it into background. It's runnng right now when I check **jobs** but I don't see it in **ps**. Is that normal?

Comment: @John Pls see my answer for some updates. Also you should be careful with `dd`, it is a rather low level utility.

Comment: @KarthikT

I did. What do you mean by low level utility? As long as it fixes my hdd I'm fine. I'm not afraid to lose the data on hdd.

Comment: @John yup, I guess collateral is quite minimal in your case, but if you had a second hard disk or something, easy to make costly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install [Disk Utility (`palimpsest`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks). First check S.M.A.R.T status. Then try to delete/format Drive (not partition). This will also show you the number of bad sectors, looks like you have quite a few. `smartcl` would also have access to this info, but Disk Utility I find is more user friendly, being GUI based.

You should be able to install it on your Linux LiveCD with a simple

```
sudo apt-get install palimpsest
```

Assuming you are on a debian derivative system. I am not sure if this will work with the GParted Live CD though, I cant find more info on if it is debian based. You can make a Ubuntu based LiveCD and work with that.

Comment: I'm using Crunchbag LiveCD(based on deb and can be run on my laptop unlike Ubuntu). I'll try the palimpsest after checking out the dd command user88311 suggested. At the moment dd command is running in the background. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: @John ah ok, good luck with `dd`!

Comment: I'm not really sure if dd is doing anything atm.
`[1]+ Running sudo dd ....the rest... &`
CPU usage is at 2% too. Is that normal?

Comment: @John dd would be writing to disk, so I wouldnt expect too high cpu usage. Your disk should be quite noisy though (if it makes noise if accessed) and `iotop` if you install it should show high numbers.

Comment: Might be useful [this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/528077/349837) with screenshots.